# Setting a timer to move a button in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, animation, timer

I have an image button on the screen and i want it to move for a certain distance on the screen when it is pressed. In swift I used to set a timer which moved it, so that I could also set the speed of this button. Is there something similar in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to use a TranslateAnimation:

```
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 100, 0, 0);
                translateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
                view.startAnimation(translateAnimation);


            }
        });
```

This will move the button 100 pixels to the right in a time interval of 1000ms = 1s

Comment: But in this animation the button goes back to its initial position. I want it to stay in his final position instead.

Comment: add the line before start of animation: translateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `ImageButton` to stay where it has moved too, like in the comments add `translateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);` before you start the animation.

Full Code:

```
        TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -150);
        translateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
        translateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        YOURIMAGEBUTTON.startAnimation(translateAnimation);
```

This will move the button 150 pixels up in a time interval of 1000ms = 1s

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                iv.animate().setDuration(100).translationX(100);
            }
        });
```